# Index.php redirect based on url

Tags: htaccess, redirects, index.php

I have been struggling with managing domains for two separate EE installations. Htaccess redirects only seem to work with the site's homepage. Anything beyond that results in a 404 error.

For example: http://domain.com is set as the root, and uses index.php to set the systempath variable thusly: $system_path = ‘./site1/‘;

My 301 redirect was pointing http://domain2.com to http://domain2.com/site2, which is what is causing the template mapping to fail. So, http://domain2.com/template_group/ results in a 404 error.

What I want to do is point both domains toward the root, and have the index.php file detect the URL and do this:

if url is domain1.com { 
    $system_path = ‘./site1/‘;
} if elseif url is domain2.com {
    $system_path = ‘./site2/‘;
}

I’m not sure what the proper syntax to use is, though. I know that CodeIgnitor has some specific functions for handling URLs.

Conversely, if someone can help me figure out why the htaccess isn't functioning. Either way, I just need to resolve the issue.

Thanks,

ty

Comment: I tried this: 
$host = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host == 'domain1.com') 
{
    $system_path = './site1/';

}
else
{
    $system_path = './site2/system/';

} 

But the domain1 isn't being detected properly.

Comment: I dont get it. Both sites operate independently yeah? Why use redirect to site 2

Comment: Because, internally, EE couldn't navigate the directory structure. Instead of http://domain2.com/template_group, it was looking for http://domain2.com/site2/template_group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the job nicely:

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
if($host == 'domain1.com') 
{
    $system_path = './system/';

}
else
{
    $system_path = './site2/system/';

}
```

Comment: So its not 2 separate EE installs? Its one install serving 2 domains?

Comment: No, it is two separate installs.